# ASP Classic: error Subscript out of range with getrows() and 2D array

Tags: arrays, vbscript, asp-classic

Could an expert look at my script? I got a strange error in Classic ASP:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0009' 
>   Subscript out of range: 'i' 
> at line 23: For i = 0 to ubound(arDataArray)

```
Set adoCn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set AdoRs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'Find out connecting credentials
strSERVERspecific=Coli(0)
strDATABASENAMEspecific=Coli(1)
strUIDspecific=Coli(2)
strPWDspecific=Coli(3)

adoCn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;server=" & strSERVERspecific & ";database=" & strDATABASENAMEspecific & ";uid=" & strUIDspecific & ";pwd=" & strPWDspecific & ";"


sSql = "Select * From Customers"
set adoRs = adoCn.Execute(sSql)

'GetRows Retrieves multiple records of a Recordset object into an array.
arDataArray = adoRs.GetRows

Response.Write "ArrayUbound=" & ubound(arDataArray) & "<br>"
For i = 0 to ubound(arDataArray)
    Response.Write "(0,i) : " & arDataArray(0,i) & " (1,i) : " & arDataArray(1, i)
    Response.Write "(2,i) : " & arDataArray(2,i) & " (3,i) : " & arDataArray(3, i) & "<BR>"
Next

adoRs.Close
adoCn.Close

set adoRs = Nothing
Set adoCn = Nothing
```

To ensure I have no more records or fields than the array can accommodate, I have taken a screen-shot of my "Customers" table (but I have not yet 10 points reputation to post images). You have to believe me that I have: 11 fields and 4 records.

I add that the function Coli(x) reads a line of a txt file located on the server side (hidden from public / httpdocs) where `x` equals to the relevant line out of the following:

- 1 means the 1st line = name / IP server
- 2 means the 2nd line = database name
- 3 means the 3rd line = user name available in the database
- 4 means the 4th line = user’s password

although apparently there is no problem with this function.

I highly appreciate any hint where to look for (I am annoyed with this error and could not sort it out for some time). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your ubound statement -- ubound without a dimension parameter will by default return the first dimension, but you're iterating (with i) on the second. In other words, your i is iterating from 0 to 10, not 0 to 3.

So you should change the errant line to:

```
For i = 0 to ubound(arDataArray, 2)
```

and that should fix it.

Comment: Indeed, it fixed it when modified as suggested. Thanks for your solution!